# Node-Red DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT

Tags: node-red

When I do a GET request from a site with self signed CERT, I get

> "DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT"

Any idea what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the http-request config tick the "Enable secure (SSL/TLS) connection" then add a new TLS config:

[image]

Then on the tls-config screen you can add the self signed certificate to the CA Certificate section or you can disable all SSL certificate checking by un tick the "Verify server certificate" box. (This is a bad idea as it makes it really easy for somebody to Man in the Middle the site)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details on how to get to In the http-request config ??

Comment: by double clicking on the node, just like any node.